# Swift 3 Date formatting trouble

Tags: date, nsdateformatter, swift3

I just converted to swift 3, and I have the following code:

```
    func timeToNSDate(_ time: String)->Date {
    var currentDate = getDate_AsString()
    let formatter  = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm"
    currentDate+=time;
    print("\n")
    print(currentDate);
    print("\n")
    var dateTemp = formatter.date(from: "2016-10-1-08-20")!
    print (dateTemp);

    let outDate = formatter.date(from: currentDate)!
    return outDate;
}
```

I'm getting the following error on the "let outDate = formatter..." line: 
*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

Interestingly, though the formatter works when an explicit date is passed. My currentDate variable however has the exact same value. My console looks like so:

```
    Optional(2016)-Optional(10)-Optional(1)-08-20
    2016-10-01 12:20:00 +0000
    fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Also, on a side note I'm noticing it's adding 4 hours to the time, is my TimeZone line not working correctly? This worked fine before I updated to swift 3.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess the error is in ``getDate_AsString()`` function. You have optional year/month/day value in the ``currentDate``

Comment: `currentDate` does *not* have the same value. The string `Optional(2016)-Optional(10)-Optional(1)-08-20` is not at all the expected string of `2016-10-1-08-20`.